# Convert hour to decimal number

Tags: macros, calculations

I'm trying to make a command for converting an hour (ex: "14:17") to a decimal value (hour + min/60 = 14.28333333333) for use in a TikZ schedule :

```
\creneau[day=1, start=13.5, end=\hourtodec{14:17}]{Maths}
```

-> Monday (day=1), 13:30 to 14:17 : Maths

I know already how to extract the numbers from 14:17 with the `xstring` package (`\StrBefore{14:17}{:}` and `\StrBehind{14:17}{:}`), but I don't know how to calculate the minutes (`calc` package works only for integers).

Comment: `tikz` itself can do a lot of math, e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\decimalday}{\hours+\minutes/60}`. Have a look at the manual, section [62 Evaluating Mathematical Expressions](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: @Tom, could you elaborate that as an answer? Looks like the most clean and simple answer so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be done by TeX itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\dechour[1]{\expandafter\dechour@i#1\@nil}
\def\dechour@i#1:#2\@nil{\strip@pt\dimexpr #1pt+#2pt/60\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{:}
\dechour{12:31}

\dechour{12:30}

\def\mbf{10:20} and \dechour{\mbf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why it's don't work when i use `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` ?

Comment: the character `:` is active in french and not a normal letter. Write `\shorthandoff{:}` before `\dechour{12:31}`

Comment: I use your solution, `\shorthandoff{:}` works fine, and now, I try `\def\mbd{09:30} \def\mbf{10:20}` but `\dechour{\mbd}` don't work : `! Argument of \dechour@i has an extra }`

Comment: see my edited answer. If you want to use macros for the time, then you need an `\expandafter`. See code

Comment: Thanks, It's work perfectly, I can now fill in my agenda without having to calculate every hour:)

Answer (score 9):

```
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand\dechour[1]{\splithour#1!}
\def\splithour#1:#2!{\FPupn\result{60 #2 / #1 +}\FPround\result\result{5}\result}

\begin{document}
\dechour{12:31}

\dechour{12:30}
\end{document}
```

This prints

> 12.51667
>   12.50000

Comment: I have this error in my document :
Runaway argument?
8:30! \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \splithour.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> temp.tex

Comment: You must be missing a `}` somewhere, or perhaps a paragraph break in `\dechour`?

Comment: Don't find : http://pastebin.com/DyuDM7zA

Comment: That snippet is not compilable. It misses `\documentclass` and definitions for `\jours` and `\creneau`.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is possible to parse such simple expressions and do such simple calculations in TeX, I prefer to use luatex for such tasks. Here is a solution in ConTeXt, where I am using a predefined lpeg pattern to match an integer.

```
\startluacode
  local C, P    = lpeg.C, lpeg.P
  local integer = lpeg.patterns.integer
  local match   = lpeg.match

  local function hourtodec(hour, min)
    return hour + min/60
  end

  local pattern = C(integer) * P(':') * C(integer) / hourtodec

  function commands.hourtodec(hour)
    return context(match(pattern, hour))
  end
\stopluacode

\def\hourtodec#1{\ctxcommand{hourtodec("#1")}}

\starttext
\hourtodec{14:17}
\stoptext
```

Almost the same solution works in LaTeX by replacing some of the convenience functions provided by ConTeXt by lua code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
  local C, P, R = lpeg.C, lpeg.P, lpeg.R
  local integer = R('09')^1
  local match   = lpeg.match

  local function hourtodec(hour, min)
    return hour + min/60
  end

  local pattern = C(integer) * P(':') * C(integer) / hourtodec

  commands = commands or {}

  function commands.hourtodec(hour)
    return tex.print(match(pattern, hour))
  end
\end{luacode}

\def\hourtodec#1{\directlua{commands.hourtodec("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\hourtodec{14:17}
\end{document}
```